# Better solution to null handling in React than if branch?

Tags: reactjs

While building React apps, I find myself struggling with handling null values.

For example in an that welcomes the user by name:

```
const Name = ({value}) => <b>Hello {value}</b>

class WelcomeMsg extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Name value={props.userName}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

If name is null, I don't to render a `Hello`.

I can add an if statement or ternary error handling which is annoying and verbose:

```
const Name = ({value}) => value ? <b>Hello {value}</b> : null
```

Or I can use some sort of Maybe construct to conditionally render the component which is even more annoying and verbose.

Is there a good alternative I'm overlooking?

Comment: `const greeting = props.userName ? <b>Hello {props.userName}</b> : null;` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing shorter I can think of is the `&&` syntax. Maybe you could do

```
const Name = ({value}) => <b>Hello {value}</b>

class WelcomeMsg extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.props.userName && <Name value={ this.props.userName }/> }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

If you don't want to do it in the parent component, you could move the `&&` into the `<Name />`.

Comment: wouldn't that result in a boolean, not a component ?

Comment: One comment, change `props.userName` to `this.props.userName`: https://jsfiddle.net/patrob10114/69z2wepo/46597/